# Creating a JSON Array?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying create a JSON Array using PHP. But I want this JSON receive a master key like this: `cidades:[{"id":"1", "nome":"Guaira"}]` and when I try  create its only create `[{"id":"1","cidade":"Guaira"}]`.

How can I do it ?

```
<?php
include '../objetos/Cidade.php';
include '../dao/CidadeDAO.php';

if($_GET['action'] == 'getCidades'){
    $idEstado = $_GET['idEstado'];  

    $dao = new CidadeDAO();
    $lista = $dao->getCidadeByEstado($idEstado);


    $arr = array();
    foreach ($lista as $object){
        $result = array("id" => $object['id'], "cidade" => $object['cidade']);
        array_push($arr, $result);
    }   

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

//output: [{"id":"1","cidade":"Guaira"},{"id":"1","cidade":"Barretos"}]
    }

```
?>
```

Comment: change $result with $result["cidades"][]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr["cidades"] = array();
array_push($arr["cidades"], $result);
```

This code produces a JSON formatted data with a key named "cidades" attached to it so that something like `cidades:[{"id":"1", "nome":"Guaira"}]` is produced. For clarity check out [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql).

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.

Comment: The code is simple...it produces a Json formatted data with a key named "cidades" attached to it so that something like cidades:[{"id":"1", "nome":"Guaira"}] is produced. For clarity check out http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: Thanks I am just a newbie...didn't know

Comment: Please don't recommend Android Hive; that tutorial (and several others on the same site) contain serious SQL injection vulnerabilities. [See more here](http://awooga.jondh.me.uk/browse?search=www.androidhive.info).

Answer (score 2):

Create a top-level array with key `'cidades'` and put your data into :

```
$arr = array('cidades' => array());
foreach ($lista as $object){
    $result = array("id" => $object['id'], "cidade" => $object['cidade']);
    array_push($arr['cidades'], $result);
}
```